# Exchange Management Shell If Else Variable

Tags: powershell, variables, if-statement

I want to enable the Exchange Mailbox from users which are in the organization unit "Test". I created this script:

```
& 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1' Connect-ExchangeServer -auto

$timestamp = Get-Date -Format G
$enablemailboxscript = Get-User -OrganizationalUnit "Test" -RecipientTypeDetails User | Enable-Mailbox -Database "Mailbox Database 2_1"

    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($enablemailboxscript)) {
        Write-Output "$timestamp 
        angelegte Benutzer: $enablemailboxscript" | Out-File D:\Administration\EnableMailboxScript.log -append       
    } else {
        Exit 1 
    }
```

My problem is, that the script always create a log record, the variable $enablemailboxscript is empty then. I want that the script only log, when there is a new enabled mailbox.

Comment: Hi, `if($enablemailboxscript)`?

Comment: works fine, thank you! :)

Comment: or `if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($enablemailboxscript))`

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the wrong way, you should use

```
if($enablemailboxscript) { ... }
```

or

```
if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($enablemailboxscript)) { ... }
```